# Creating a function that outputs a series of two-by-two tables

Tags: r, function, gtsummary

Using the gtsummary package, I want to create a function that lets me output a series of two by two tables using a large number of variables. I have the function below, when running it using the dummy data, the function throws the following error. Can anyone help with this?

```
Note: Using an external vector in selections is ambiguous.
ℹ Use `all_of(y)` instead of `y` to silence this message.
ℹ See <https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/faq-external-vector.html>.
This message is displayed once per session.
```

This is the dummy data

```
# download pacman package if not installed, otherwise load it
if(!require(pacman)) install.packages(pacman)

# loads relevant packages using the pacman package
pacman::p_load(gtsummary) # for the twobytwo table
     

dummy <-data.frame(city = sample(c("SF", "AR", "NYC","MN"),13000,replace = TRUE),
                       city_2 = sample(c("SF", "AR", "NYC","MN"),13000,replace = TRUE),
                       year = sample(as.factor(c(1990, 2000, 1999, 1989)),13000,replace = TRUE)
    )
```

This is the function

```
crosstab_func <- function(data, x, y) {
  
  out <- gtsummary::tbl_cross(data,
              row = x, 
              col = y) 
    
  return(out)
}
```

...and this is the function call using the combo function.

```
result <- combn(names(dummy), 2, function(x) 
                crosstab_func(dummy, x[1], x[2]), simplify = FALSE)
```

And one of the outcomes I am looking for is this...[image]

Comment: You show loading `data.table` but never use it, and you do not show `dplyr` (or `magrittr`) yet you're using `%>%`. It would help to review what packages are really necessary for your question, as it is currently inconsistent. Finally, *"it does not seem to work"* is also unclear: if there are warnings or errors, include them; if the output is just incorrect, show some output and why you think it is wrong. Using your sample data, please provide at least one of the expected output components you are expecting.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. Hopefully now the question is more detailed enough to answer

Comment: I'm not at a computer to write the full solution. If all you need to do is remove the note about external vector selection, add `all_of()` around the x and y arguments in `tbl_cross()`.

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg that was spot on!! That is 2/2 of my questions, you are on a streak my friend! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This might be simpler in base R.

```r
set.seed(42) # for reproducibility
dummy <- data.frame(city = sample(c("SF", "AR", "NYC","MN"), 13000, replace = TRUE),
                    city_2 = sample(c("SF", "AR", "NYC","MN"), 13000, replace = TRUE),
                    year = sample(as.factor(c(1990, 2000, 1999, 1989)), 13000, replace = TRUE)
     )
head(dummy)
#   city city_2 year
# 1   SF     MN 1990
# 2   SF    NYC 2000
# 3   SF     SF 1999
# 4   SF     MN 1999
# 5   AR     MN 2000
# 6   MN    NYC 1990
```

From here:

```r
combn(names(dummy), 2, function(nms) {
  frm <- paste("~", paste(nms, collapse = " + "), collapse = "")
  addmargins(             # adds the 'Sum' columns/rows
    xtabs(frm, data = dummy)
  )
}, simplify = FALSE)
# [[1]]
#      city_2
# city     AR    MN   NYC    SF   Sum
#   AR    798   791   823   833  3245
#   MN    806   803   841   782  3232
#   NYC   812   776   785   829  3202
#   SF    785   834   846   856  3321
#   Sum  3201  3204  3295  3300 13000
# [[2]]
#      year
# city   1989  1990  1999  2000   Sum
#   AR    831   810   833   771  3245
#   MN    777   870   818   767  3232
#   NYC   779   796   831   796  3202
#   SF    817   826   850   828  3321
#   Sum  3204  3302  3332  3162 13000
# [[3]]
#       year
# city_2  1989  1990  1999  2000   Sum
#    AR    807   797   819   778  3201
#    MN    803   816   820   765  3204
#    NYC   842   839   821   793  3295
#    SF    752   850   872   826  3300
#    Sum  3204  3302  3332  3162 13000
```